# Maintaining Object Model in multiple languages

Tags: java, python, class, yaml

I'm writing a basic SDK for Java & Python (and potentially other languages in the future) consumers of an API (REST as well as message-queue orientated responses).

Instead of maintaining separate per-language descriptions, I was wondering if there was perhaps a way to define classes and enums in something like YAML which could be automatically be converted into appropriate objects in each language.

I imagine I could write the objects in C and then make per-language bindings - but this seems a bit hacky as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON to represent your object model and translate it to objects in each of the language you are using.

Here are some relevant articles that will help you get started. 
How to convert Java object to / from JSON (Jackson)
https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/

https://realpython.com/python-json/#encoding-and-decoding-custom-python-objects
Working With JSON Data in Python

Another option is Protocol Buffers though it is not as favorite as JSON when working with REST apis.